# Prevent stack animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a javascript/jquery rookie, but I try to put in place a an interactive page containing multiple divs. These Divs enlight when we pass the mouse over and turn back to normal when mouse leaves the div. The div enlarges when clicked, and a "back" button" must turn back the div to "normal" state. My problem is the behavior of the div when click the back button, and it starts to get back to normal but enlarges again afterward. I know I could resolve the problem by moving the "button" out of the div, but is there any other solution ?
Also, how to "stop" the opacity change when enlarging the DIV ? Tried the stop() function in various scenarios but without success so far...
Thanks for the help.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='back_button'>BACK</div>
</div>
```

And here is for the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }, function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    }).click(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: "600px",
            height: "600px",
            opacity: 1
        });
        $('#back_button').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('#back_button').click(function () {
        $(this).stop( true, true ).parent().animate({
            width: "200px",
            height: "100px"
        });
    });
});
```

I also created an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm5f6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the click on the back button from propagating up to the parent, and you can use a class to disable the hover events when the element is enlarged.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').hover(function () {
        if ( ! $(this).hasClass('large') ) $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }, function () {
        if ( ! $(this).hasClass('large') ) $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    }).click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "600px",
            height: "600px",
            opacity: 1
        }).addClass('large');
        $('#back_button').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('#back_button').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().animate({
            width: "200px",
            height: "100px"
        }).removeClass('large');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Vm5f6/8/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo, but what about opacity change ?

Comment: You don't want the hover effects when it's enlarged ?

Comment: yes indeed, that's it, I want to avoid changing opacity when enlarging the DIV

Comment: I did't see that you've been changin your code, many thanks for your help Adeno ! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you Adeno, I've noticed that in your fiddle, once the div enlarged and retracted, the hover animation doesn't work anymore, did I missed something ? thanks again !

Comment: figured it out by moving the "removeClass('large')" after .parent(). Hope it will help somebody. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please use this updated code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#container').hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
        }).click(function (e) {

            if(e.target.id=="back_button" || $(this).width()>200){

                return;
            }
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width: "600px",
                height: "600px",
                opacity: 1
            });
            $('#back_button').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        });
        $('#back_button').click(function () {
            $('#container').animate({
                width: "200px",
                height: "100px",

            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it keeps changing opacity when enlarging the div, which I would like to avoid as well. I only want to change opacity when the div is in a "normal" state.

Comment: you can check the with of div and then make a check

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I don't explain myself properly. Before clicking to enlarge the div, you can notice that putting the mouse over the div make it change his opacity, which is the good behaviour. However when we click on the div to enlarge it, it still changing opacity when leaving the div, what I would like to avoid. Is there a way to correct this ? thanks again for your patience and your help :)